# User-defined windows service does not start - 1053 error

Tags: windows-services, instsrv

I am trying to convert a console exe into a Windows service running on Windows 2003. I used the Windows Resource Kit tools to install it as a service (followed the information in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890). However, when I try to start the service I get a 1053 error - "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

May the this can help.[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374944/running-batch-script-as-windows-service)

My issue still open but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to the server console and start it. Remote in won't work sometime.